# how can I avoid recurrent neural network from overtraining?

Tags: neural-network

I'm using a recurrent neural network for prediction. how should i avoid from overtraining? I've used gradient decent for parameter updates. the following figure shows the training and validation error for 500 epoch [training and validation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQt18.jpg)

Comment: You probably get a better answer on stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: thanks for your comment.

Comment: Preventing overtraining is an art. You might have some luck with dropout and early stopping.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few strategies that help against overfitting:

1. Regularization. You can add dropout or use L1 or L2 regularization on the weights.
2. Use a smaller model (i.e. have less parameters to fit)
3. Add random noise to your data
4. Add training data (if you can't get more natural data, you can perhaps generate it synthetically)
5. Use early stopping. This just means stopping training before it starts to overfit.

A typical approach is this: Use a big model, and use dropout and maybe also L2. Try a few different values for the amount of regularization, and use the best one. Monitor validation error as you train, and pick the model where it is the lowest (early stopping).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I don't know if you saw my error chart, my problem is that because the network is recurrent, the parameter update formulas are not accurate, and as shown in the error chart, training error does not descend through time and it has ups and downs and so is the validation error. so either early stopping is not option here or I'm making a big mistake!

Comment: It looks like your network is having trouble learning (considering the flat training and validation error upto ~epoch 200). Hard to say what the problem might be without knowing more about the problem you're solving and the network architecture your using. Also, I don't know what error function you're using, but it seems like the error is close to 0. This, in a sense, indicates that there's little left to learn - that might be a problem.

Comment: The circles represent neurons. The objective is to predict the price of the next days using previous days prices. There are 2 inputs (n=2), 3 neurons in the hidden layer and 5 outputs (k=5) so the network has 6 inputs (n+k-1=2+5-1=6). Tansig is used as transfer function of the first layer, and purelin in the output layer.  I know its impossible to achieve this goal but my problem is not the low performance, I want to know when to stop training, and usually the training error descends through time, but in my network it is swinging. I don't know if its normal or I'm doing something wrong!

Comment: Hard to say. Yes, you usually see the training error go down, even if that is purely because the net it has memorized the training data. I suspect in your case though that the network doesn't really have the capacity to even memorize any data as it has very few parameters - RNNs are often used with millions of parameters.

Comment: millions???! when i use more than 15 neurons in the hidden layer it the outputs tend to infinity!!! I've tried every possible case, this is the best structure I could find. You can see this paper 
[link] (https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=A+two-step-ahead+recurrent+neural+network+for+stream-flow+forecasting&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp=) Its a recurrent network used for prediction and it also has few parameters

Comment: Yes, millions :) Even in the paper you linked inputs and outputs are vectors. But it depends on the task, it doesn't make sense with very low dimensional inputs and outputs. It's impossible to tell if there is anything wrong with your model, since the function you're trying to learn almost certainly can't be learned in the first place. To test if the model works, you can try to fit other data, i.e. a simple curve you generate yourself.

Comment: Have a look at my simple implementation here:https://github.com/rajarsheem/playing-with-RNNs/blob/master/int_seq.ipynb
If you need explanation, create an issue there.